# Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable from class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a choose your own adventure turn based combat emulator. It's my first project ever so I have been running into many walls. This one I just do not understand though. Everything that is referencing this Slime() class is coming back as not an integer or 'is not subscript able'.

```
class Monster:
    def __init__(self, hp, defense, speed, attacks=None):
        self.hp = hp
        self.defense = defense
        self.speed = speed
        self.attacks = attacks


class Slime(Monster):
    def __init__(self, hp, defense, speed):
        super().__init__(self, hp, defense, speed)
        if self.attacks is None:
            self.attacks = {"Slap": randint(5, 10), "Gurgle": None, "Split": None}
```

Also feels like it is related but since I called the super() of the parent class it will not accept the int from "Slap" in my Slime's attacks.

I instantiate slime:

```
slime = Slime(50, 5, 5)
```

but it didn't like that either.
Feels like i'm missing some core happening.

Comment: When i run your code, I get no error. You'll have to include more of your code for us to know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
import random
class Monster:
    def __init__(self, hp, defense, speed, attacks=None):
        self.hp = hp
        self.defense = defense
        self.speed = speed
        self.attacks = attacks


class Slime(Monster):
    def __init__(self, hp, defense, speed):
        super().__init__(hp, defense, speed)
        if self.attacks is None:
            self.attacks = {"Slap": random.randint(5, 10), "Gurgle": None, "Split": None}

slime = Slime(50, 5, 5)
print(slime.__dict__)

{'hp': 50, 'defense': 5, 'speed': 5, 'attacks': {'Slap': 6, 'Gurgle': None, 'Split': None}}
```

No need to pass the self instance to the super, the __init__ method gets it directly from the __new__ method, here you passed one instace of Slime to the Monster class.